# Differentiating cosine squared of x

Tags: calculus

I am trying to differentiate with respect to $x$, $y = \cos^2{x}$

Using the chain rule and my working out is this:

\begin{align*}\frac{dy}{dx} &= 2 \cos(x)(-\sin(x)) \\
      &= -2 \sin x
 \end{align*}
I am not sure how to get to the correct answer of $-\sin{(2x)}$.

Should I be using the chain rule or maybe the product rule?

Please help, Thanks in advance

Comment: I have typeset your question with LaTeX.  Please double-check that I correctly transcribed it.

Comment: Your differentiation is correct.   $2\cos x(-\sin x) \ne -2 \sin x$ but $2\cos x(-\sin x)=-2\sin{x}\cos{x}=-\sin{2x}$

Comment: You can also use that $\cos^2(x)=\frac 1 2 (1+\cos(2x))$ and differentiate that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$2\cos (x)(-\sin(x))=-2\cos(x)\sin(x)=-\sin(2x)$

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, what trig identity have you used.. thanks

Comment: $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$

Answer (score 1):

### Chain Rule

To differentiate $y = \cos^2x$ with respect to $x$, one must apply the chain rule as shown:

$$ \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \cdot \frac{du}{dx}$$
Firstly, $ \,\,let \,\,\, u = \cos x \,\,$
One can then differentiate this with respect to $x$ such that $$\frac{du}{dx} = -sinx$$
Then, $ \,\,let \,\,\, y = u^2$
Differentiate $y$ with respect to $u$ such that $\frac{dy}{du} = 2u$

Next, one can substitute $u$ back in to make $$\frac{dy}{du} = 2\cos x$$

Thus, $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -2\sin x \cdot \cos x$$

### Double Angle Formula Simplification

Using the formula:
$$\sin(2u) = 2\sin u\cos u$$
We can simplify to:

## $$\frac{dy}{dx} = -\sin(2x)$$

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake there - you misuse the trigonometric identity. Look at http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html

It's $$2 \cdot \cos(x)\cdot \sin(x) = \sin(2x)$$
Not $$\cos(x)\cdot \sin(x) = \sin(s)$$